# Getting value to stay selected after post back for a drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, code-behind

I have code behind code in my page load that sets a drop down lists text and values.  WHen ever I select a value, it reloads the page because i have auto post back on.  I need the value to stay selected even after post back.  How would I go about doing this?  Below is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>
      { "Month", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"};

    DropDownListMonth.DataSource = list;
    DropDownListMonth.DataBind();
    DropDownListMonth.SelectedIndex = 0;

    foreach (ListItem item in DropDownListMonth.Items)
    {
        int i = 0;
        string month = Convert.ToString(i);
        item.Value = month;
        i = Convert.ToInt32(month);
        i++;
    }   
}
```

Comment: If any answer solved your problem you should accept it by clicking on the check-mark beside it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Page property called [Page.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that indicates whether the page is being rendered for the first time or is being loaded in response to a postback.

So you can use this property with `if` conditional block to avoid the re-binding of ddl.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
      List<string> list = new List<string>
      { "Month", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"};

    DropDownListMonth.DataSource = list;
    DropDownListMonth.DataBind();
    DropDownListMonth.SelectedIndex = 0;

    foreach (ListItem item in DropDownListMonth.Items)
    {
        int i = 0;
        string month = Convert.ToString(i);
        item.Value = month;
        i = Convert.ToInt32(month);
        i++;
    } 
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [`IsPostBack()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) verification:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack())
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>
      { "Month", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"};

        DropDownListMonth.DataSource = list;
        DropDownListMonth.DataBind();
        DropDownListMonth.SelectedIndex = 0;

        foreach (ListItem item in DropDownListMonth.Items)
        {
            int i = 0;
            string month = Convert.ToString(i);
            item.Value = month;
            i = Convert.ToInt32(month);
            i++;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: got it to work thanks to you and another page i read.  thank you

Comment: would love to know why the negative score :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DropDownListMonth.DataSource = list;
DropDownListMonth.DataBind();
DropDownListMonth.SelectedIndex = 0;
string selectedValue=DropDownListMonth.SelectedItem.Tostring();
foreach (ListItem item in DropDownListMonth.Items)
{
       int i = 0;
       string month = Convert.ToString(i);
       item.Value = month;
       i = Convert.ToInt32(month);
       i++;
       if(item.Value.Tostring()==selectedValue)
       {
         item.Selected=true;
       }
}
```